# How to install a npm scoped module on Microsoft Azure Web Sites

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service, npm-install

My company has private scoped `npm` modules i.e. the ones starting with `@mycompanyscope/mymodule`. By defaults all scoped modules in npm are private so you have to login first before publish

```
npm login
Username:myusername
Password:**********
npm publish
```

The scoped module must have the property `name` with a scope in the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@mycompanyscope/mymodule"
}
```

and the `private` key must be removed.

As soon as you login you get a `token` in the `.npmrc` file in your `$HOME` folder, that is like

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
scope=mycompanyscope
```

At this point everything is properly setup to `publish` and `install` in this machine. If you grant access to other users, they can do `npm login` on their machines and get a token to work from there.

The problems come on the server side, depending on your server. On Heroku it should work as explained [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/ci-server-config).

My server environment is Azure Web Sites. According to some docs, you should upload your `.npmrc` file to Azure during the deploying phase, and that would awesome, if I would have a way to get a token for that machine.
If I try to login to `Kudu PowerShell`, the fact is that I just cannot login, the login process hangs at some point:

```
Kudu Remote Execution Console
Type 'exit' then hit 'enter' to get a new powershell process.
Type 'cls' to clear the console

PS D:\home> npm login
Username: mycompany
Password: *********
Email: (this IS public) npm@mycompany.com
```

so that I cannot generate any token from this machine. So how can I grant access here to let the `npm install` to run correctly for private scoped modules?

**[UPDATE]**
Thanks to the answer below I was able to deploy the npm scoped module (@ mycompanyscope/myModule) to Azure Web Sites, creating the `.npmrc` file in the project root folder (where the `package.json` is) and then writing there the token obtained after the `npm login`, and adding the `registry` to the `npmjs.org` registry:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
scope=mycompanyscope
@mycompanyscope:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to `npm login` your private npm registry on your local machine, to generate a `.npmrc` file in your node.js application, then deploy to Azure Web App with your application.

Please refer to https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2015/10/13/working-with-a-private-npm-registry-in-azure-web-apps.html for more details.

Any update or further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The solution you mention is using `myget` to host the `npm private registry` so that you can add this to your `.npmrc` file like `npm install --save --registry https://www.myget.org/F/demo-site/npm/` but I'm using `npmjs.com` private modules, and I don't find any example adding a registry for it to my `.npmrc`.

Comment: Its the same, as when you run the command `npm login` the default registry url is `registry.npmjs.org`. And according the description at https://www.npmjs.com/settings/tokens, you can manually create the `.npmrc` the set the auth token in this page, to let your Azure Web Apps environment to download your private modules.

Comment: I confirm that this is the solution. Thank you. I have updated the question.